# SQL Server : replace script error gives me String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, truncated

I am self taught with SQL Server. I been using the replace script lately. I have to replace a string inside of a `varchar` column.

An example of what I need to change is `15151500001500000000` where I need to change the last `00` to `10`

This is the script I am using:

```
UPDATE xxxxx
   SET craftname = REPLACE(craftname, 00, 10)
 WHERE craftname like '%00'
```

However it gives me this error every time

> String or binary data would be truncated.

I searched around the net and from what I can see most common reason is that the column is getting to big but here I am replacing 2 digits with 2 digits so that shouldn't happen.

Any ideas?

Comment: really? `REPLACE(craftname, 00,10)` SQL server allows that?  I'm guessing it converts the integers to strings and then uses them in the replace operation. so you get `REPLACE(craftname, '0','10')` which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using strings instead of integers:

```
UPDATE xxxxx
   SET craftname = REPLACE(craftname, '00', '10')
 WHERE craftname like '%00';
```

The problem with your version is that every `0` is replaced by `10`, which increases the length of the string.  The integers are turned into strings using "reasonable" representations, so `00` becomes `'0'`, rather than `'00'`.

The above still won't do what you want, because it will replace every occurrence of `00` with `10`.  I included it to show you how to fix the run-time error.

If you just want to change the last two characters, don't use `REPLACE()`.  Instead:

```
UPDATE xxxxx
   SET craftname = LEFT(craftname, len(craftname) - 2) + '10'
 WHERE craftname like '%00';
```